# Clicking a button centers the wrong carousel (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have it so that if you click on any of the numbered buttons, the next/prev buttons, or an image in a carousel the script will adjust the carousel to move it to the center of the viewport. However, I noticed that if you click on any of those buttons associated with the second carousel, the page will scroll all the way back up and adjust to the first carousel. How can I get it so that the correct carousel is adjusted? Example being, pressing any buttons associated with #2 carousel adjusts #2 carousel or pressing any buttons for #3 carousel adjusts the #3 carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true
  });
});

var el = $('.owl-carousel .lazyOwl');
$('.owl-carousel, .owl-thumb-item').on('click', function(e) {

  //  var el = $(".lazyOwl", this);
  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
  var elHeight = el.height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var offset;

  if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
    offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
  } else {
    offset = elOffset;
  }
  var speed = 700;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, speed);
});

var animations = new Array();
// queue all
$(".owl-thumb-item").each(function() {
  animations.push($(this));
});

// start animating
doAnimation(animations.shift());

function doAnimation(image) {
  image.fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // wait until animation is done and recurse if there are more animations
    if (animations.length > 0) doAnimation(animations.shift());
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/662/

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it right! Instead of:

```
//var el = $(".lazyOwl", this);
```

You should use this:

```
var el = $(this);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/665/

The jumping "delay" is caused by the animation. If you remove the animation it shows the right position immediatelly:

```
//  $('html, body').animate({
//    scrollTop: offset
//  }, speed);
  $('html, body').scrollTop(offset);
```

Comment: When you press the numbered buttons though, there's sort of a "delay" happening. Like it shifts slightly before finally committing the whole way.